# Django rest framework serializer method field

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Not sure if this question is appropriate for here, but I can't really find any data on it. 
I was wondering how much of a performance hit is using `SerializerMethodField` inside my `serializer`? Should I restart to writing `queries` by hand if most of my `fields` are calculated `real-time` based on `query parameters`?

Comment: I am not exactly sure why you need to calculate the fields in real-time. What I would do, I would choose the subset of all the required fields and definitely reuse the `SerializerMethodField`. Writing your own queries will become slower in the overall performance since in the rest-framework you can easily setup  caching as well

Comment: Not sure what you mean choosing a subset of all the required fields and reusing the SerializerMethodField? I can only have one method per field, or is there a way to calculate multiple fields at the same time (because yes there are some values I could reuse throughout)?

They are calculated in real time because more or less all data is reliant on a datepicker on the page (so the user always sees this week's data when visiting the page, or he can choose to view today, yesterday, last week, this month, last year, etc)

Comment: Usually you would want to retrieve all the data upfront using as few queries as possible and not hit the database inside serializer as it would be repeating those queries for every record in the list. Check out  django's `prefetch_related()` and `annotate()`, and you really need to enable sql log to see what queries are actually executed, you might be surprised by the huge number of queries a simple looking list could produce if not being careful.

Comment: How can I do that with viewsets?